# Change Wordpress menu when scrolling

Tags: wordpress, menu

Can someone tell me please how can i have different top menu when scrolling. You can see example on this site http://www.pizzafan.gr. It is static menu and if you scroll the menu items are changing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace some coding in your header.html
First, you need to replace your below code:

```
<div class="sticky_logo_left">
        <a href="http://www.pizzafan.gr/el"><img src="/assets/site/images/logo_mobile.png" alt="Pizza Fan Logo" width="140" class="moblogo"></a>
    </div>
```

From:

```
<div class="sticky_logo_left">
<a href="http://www.pizzafan.gr/el"><img     src="/assets/site/images/logo_mobile.png" alt="Pizza Fan Logo" width="140" class="moblogo"></a>
<ul class="quick_menu">
            <li class="first desktop">
                <a href="http://www.pizzafan.gr/el">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/home.png" alt="" class="desktop">
                    <!--<img src="/assets/site/images/home-mobile.png" alt="" class="mobile" height="18">-->
                    <span>Αρχική</span>
                </a>                      
            </li>
            <li class="first">
                <a href="http://www.pizzafan.gr/el/menu/pizzas">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/slice.png" alt="" class="desktop">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/slice-mobile.png" alt="" class="mobile" height="18">
                    <span>Menu</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="first">
                <a href="http://www.pizzafan.gr/el/restaurants">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/shopping.png" alt="" class="desktop">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/shopping_mobile.png" alt="" class="mobile" height="18">
                    <span>Καταστήματα</span>
                </a>                      
            </li>
            <li class="hover" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#callBackModal">
                <a href="javascript:void();" class="callmeback">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/call.png" alt="" class="desktop">
                    <img src="/assets/site/images/call_mobile.png" alt="" class="mobile" height="18">
                    <span>Call Me Back</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And Then, change your static menu images with this color code: #00742D
just make your menu images with above mention color code.

and you will see same menu items in your scrolling menu check this similar scrolling [menu example](http://www.couponmaal.com).. Menu both in simple and scrolling with same menu items/ options.

Comment: Thanks i will try that.